# JQuery http post request between docker containers fails

Tags: php, jquery, mongodb, docker, rest

I am new in web development and especially in Docker and I am trying to use Docker for a webpage I am working on as part of a semester project. I have created 3 containers. One for my application logic (ui), one for the REST api service (both with php:7.2-apache images) and one for a MongoDB. I have tried many different things, so there may be some unnecessary code below. The problem seems to be that the POST request made by the $.post part of the index.php code (see below) is not done properly, as I am not redirected to the welcome.php page of my web app and I cannot find the reason why.

The docker-compose.yml file is the following:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  mongo_db:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongodb
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "270187:27017"
    expose:
      - "27017"
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/var/lib/mongo
      - .mongo/mongoinit.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: plh513   
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: plh513       
  
  restapi:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile1
    container_name: restapi
    ports:
      - "27018:27018"
    expose:
      - "27018"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
    depends_on:
      - mongo_db
    links:
      - mongo_db

  app: 
    build:
     context: .
     dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: applogic
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    expose:
      - "80"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
    depends_on:
      - restapi

volumes:
  mongo-data: {}
```

The Dockerfile (Dockerfile1 is similar) I am using is:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache 

RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y git zlib1g-dev \
 && docker-php-ext-install zip \
 && apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev libicu-dev g++ \
 && docker-php-ext-configure intl \
 && docker-php-ext-install intl \
 && apt-get install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev pkg-config libssl-dev \
 && echo "extension=mongodb.so" > $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/mongodb.ini \
 && pecl install mongodb \
 && a2enmod rewrite \
 && sed -i 's!/var/www/html!/var/www/src!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf \
 && mv /var/www/html /var/www/src \
 && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer \
  | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

WORKDIR /var/www
```

The index.php code (HTML and JQuery included) for the login page is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=yes">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
    <title>LOGIN</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="loginstyle.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="center">
     <form id="loginform" action="index.php" method="post">

        <div class="imgcontainer">
            <img src="logo1.png" alt="Logo" class="logo">
        </div>
        
        <div class="container">
            <label><b>Username</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>
            <label><b>Password</b></label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="pass" required>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" id="login" value="Login">
        <div class="errormsg" id="errormsg"></div>    
     </form>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    // JQuery actions for HTML body content
    // Action when the login button in clicked
        $("#login").click(function(){
        // create a variable based on the user's input in class = container
        var credentials = {
            uname: $(".container input[name='uname']")[0].value,
            pass: $(".container input[name='pass']")[0].value
        };
        var url = document.location.protocol + "//" + document.location.hostname + ":27018";
        var api = "url:27018/user_validate.php";
        
        $.post(api,JSON.stringify(credentials),function(data,status,xhr){
            var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
            // if server_data.message is an error case
            if(jsonData.message == "user_not_confirmed"){
                $("#errormsg").text("Login failed: This user has not yet been confirmed by an administrator");
                $("#errormsg").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");
            }else if(jsonData.message == "wrong_credentials"){
                $("#errormsg").text("Login failed: Wrong username or password");
                $("#errormsg").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");
            // user successfully logged in
            }else if(jsonData.message == "success_login"){
                if(jsonData.validate == "true"){
                    sessionStorage.setItem("already_logged", true);
                    sessionStorage.setItem("id", jsonData.id);
                    sessionStorage.setItem("username", jsonData.username);
                    sessionStorage.setItem("name", jsonData.name);
                    sessionStorage.setItem("surname", jsonData.surname);
                    sessionStorage.setItem("role", jsonData.role);
                    sessionStorage.setItem("confirmed", jsonData.confirmed);
                    window.location.replace("localhost/welcome.php");
                }
            }

        },"json");
    });
</script>
</html>
```

The user_validate.php file (part of the REST api) is:

```
<?php 
// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

// validate user
// include database file
include_once 'mongodb_config.php';

$dbname = 'plh513';
$collection = 'users';
// DB connection - works fine
$db = new DbManager();
$conn = $db->getConnection();

// read data from HTTP body and set variables $uname, $password
$contents = file_get_contents('php://input');
$contents = stripslashes(html_entity_decode($contents));
$data = json_decode($contents,true);

// Read a single user from db (at variable $user_data)
$option = ['limit' => 1];
$read = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($data, $option);
$user_data = $conn->executeQuery("$dbname.$collection", $read);

// actions based on query's result
foreach ($user_data as $user){
    if(empty($user))
    {   
        echo json_encode(
            array("message" => "wrong_credentials")
        );
    }
    else if($user->confirmed == "0")
    {
        echo json_encode(
            array("message" => "user_not_confirmed")
        );
    }
    else
    {
        echo json_encode(
            array("message" => "success_login",
                "validate" => "true",
                "id" => $user->_id,
                "username" => $user->username,
                "name" => $user->name,
                "surname" => $user->surname,
                "role" => $user->role,
                "confirmed" => $user->confirmed
            )
        );
    }
}

?>
```

I have made sure that the MongoDB is working properly and executes the queries inside user_validate.php.

Any suggestion of why I am always redirected to localhost/index.php and not to localhost/welcome.php, while using the correct credentials?

Comment: I suggest adding some more logs for debugging. For example, checking the value for for `var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);` with `console.log(jsonData)` in the `index.php` file.

Comment: It is like the function(data,status,xhr) is never executed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.